# how get mouse enter/exit events on Sharepoint 2010 List/Document Lib

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a req that when user hovers mouse over folder/list item i need to show preview of it .

I did lot of search on internet but didn't find anything useful.Some link mentioned about using of CE Webpart for mouse over event on list item but i don't want to go that way.

is there any sharepoint feature like we have SP event feature  (item adding,deletion etc) which can be applied on multiple servers by deploying WSP etc..

Answer (score 1):

Mouse hover event in any web application happens on client side i.e, browser and that is done by using Javascript or a javascript library like JQuery. You can then use a combination of the Ajax/SP.UI/Client object model/Jquery technologies to fetch data from server and display the data you need.

Displaying a tooltip/preview for a list item is fairly simple when compared to displaying thumbnail/preview for a document.

Remember, document in the library can be of any extension - word doc, pdf, excel, visio, infopath etc... Although requirement sounds simple it could take a very long time to implement it. There are some products out there with just this functionality but very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sharepoint Designer to include jQuery in your master page (or in a web editor webpart). After that, implement SPServices (A Sharepoint jQuery interaction library) in order to get the list item info. Using jQuery UI, open a modal window with your info.

To do so, You will need to use some CAML querys. CAML query will allow You to get all item info by its name or ID.

jQuery:
http://jquery.com

SPServices:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

jQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just need to know how i can get mousehover (enter/leave) events on list items & how i can get that item data in Mouse enter event , then in MouseEnter event i'll be using my JS function to perform my logic. i don't want to use jquery approch . Is there any thing avialable from sharepoint which i can use to get mouseEnter/exit event. Editing masterpage will not suffice for me because i need to perform this on multiple sharepoint server so any solution which can be deployed on server like creating SP feature/WSP will help me